X2 smartphones (IOS or Android) connecting via BLE
Is there anything that fundamentally prevents the following situation?
Imagine you have two smartphones with bluetooth low energy capabilities. I am asking about any combination of IOS or Android devices.
Both phones simultaneously act as both BLE peripherals and BLE centrals. Each phone connects as a central to the peripheral element of the other phone.
Is this possible?
My use case is the following: I want both phones to advertise the same BLE service (Q). Then when the phones come into contact range, I want them to automatically connect to each other and read all of the characteristics of Q off of the other phone.

It is explicitly prohibited by the Bluetooth SIG to establish multiple connections between the same two devices. This restriction is outlined in the Bluetooth Core Specification v6.0, Vol 6, Part B, Section 4.5 (Connection State):

When two devices are in a connection, the two devices act in different
roles. A Link Layer in the Central Role is called a Central. A Link
Layer in the Peripheral Role is called a Peripheral. The Central
controls the timing of a connection event. A connection event is a
point of synchronization between the Central and the Peripheral.
There shall be only one ACL connection, whether or not established, between two LE device addresses (including two different Resolvable
Private Addresses that resolve to the same IRK). An initiator shall
not send a connection request to an advertiser it is already connected
to. A periodic advertiser shall not send a connection request to a
synchronized device that it is already connected to.

This specification explicitly prevents the scenario described in your question. When a connection exists between two devices, they act as Central and Peripheral, respectively, and only a single ACL (Asynchronous Connection-Less) connection is allowed between them.
In your use case, where both phones act as both BLE peripherals and centrals simultaneously to connect to each other and read characteristics of the same BLE service (Q), this setup is not feasible under the Bluetooth specification. Each phone would be restricted to a single ACL connection with the other, preventing simultaneous connections as Central and Peripheral.
